# How to give input as single decimal in a number String for the calculator program?

Tags: android

As per the below code when I give the input by pressing the Decimal button. It takes multiple times while I want single times. But if I extend the text by using the operator then decimal should be accepted.
Example: Current: 45..67.9+.367.8-3.6.7 (In number we can give input multiple times)
`Expected:45.679+.3678-3.67` (Expecting only one time in a number string).

I trying to apply the boolean condition as mentioned

```
boolean isDotExist=processor.contains(".");
if (  isDotExist==false)
```

then it takes only one time but I am trying to put again after using the operator.

```
    btnDecimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
            if (  isDotExist==false){
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + ".");
            }
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Reading this post might help: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
btnDecimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        
        boolean isDotExist=processor.contains(".");
        processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
        if (!isDotExist){
            tvProcessor.setText(processor + ".");
        }
        
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarification...